# public Student retrieveById(int id)

Tags: java

```
public class Roster extends ArrayList<Student> 
{
public boolean containsStudent(String ln)
{ 
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter last name of student: ");
    String lName = user_input.next();
    for (Student student : this)
    {
        if (student.getLastName().equals(lName)) 
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

How can I fix the error in the next method:

```
public Student retrieveByld(int id)
{
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the ID of the student: ");
    String idNum = user_input.next(); 
    for (Student student : this)
    {
        if (student.getID().equals(idNum)) 
        return student.getFullName();
    }
    return " "; 
}
```

Error: int cannot be dereferenced. I'm guessing I cannot compare to ints using the .equals method but how can I without changing the syntax too much.

Given the id, I have to make the program find the student in the list and return that students full name. If student not found I have to return null. If it helps here's my Student class.

```
public class Student
{
    private String lName, fName;
    private int idNum;

public Student(int id, String fn, String ln)
{
lName = ln;
fName = fn;
idNum = id;
}

public String getFullName()
{
    return fName + " " + lName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lName;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return fName;
}



public int getID()
{
    return idNum;
}

public String toString()
{
    return fName + " " + lName + " " + idNum;
}
}
```

Comment: funny, but you already asked a question about the same homework:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192196/public-boolean-containsstudentstring-ln

Answer (score 1):

`int`s do not have the `equals()` method to see if they are equal, they use the `==` operator, as it's a primitive type. What you're looking for to change is the line `if (student.getID().equals(idNum))`, which should be:  `if (student.getID() == idNum)`.

Comment: You're right and I was thinking but seemed to simple lol. But not it's saying can't find the getFullName() method even though it was in the student class.

Comment: @AlshadayG I do not see any getFullName() method in what you posted.. Maybe use the getFirstName() and getLastName() methods combined? Like `return getFirstName()+" "+getLastName();`

Comment: Ya sorry forgot it when I posted question but it's still gives me the error even after I had added it.

Comment: `public String geFullName()` <- typo?

Comment: In the code, it's just calling getFirstName(), not student.getFirstName().

Comment: Okay I took in both your suggestions. Obviously the typo was a big problem but not it's highlighting the parenthesis after student.getFullName and saying incompatible types.

Comment: In your method declaration it says you are returning a Student - either change that to String or return a Student.

Comment: Oh okay and this might sound stupid, but how do I return a student.

Comment: Oh okay and for the null would I return a " " or -1

Answer (score 1):

Your getID() method returns an int, which is a primitive type, meaning it does not have any methods, including the "equals" that you're trying to call. So, either you need to change your idNum from a String to an int, or you need to change what you get back from student.getID() to a String.

Since you're using a Scanner, that has a nextInt() method, which will return the user input as an int. Then you just check for equals using the standard == operator.

Something like this:

```
public Student retrieveByld(int id)
{
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the ID of the student: ");
    int idNum = user_input.nextInt(); 
    for (Student student : this)
    {
        if (student.getID() == idNum) 
        return getFullName();
    }
    return " "; 
}
```

Comment: Also, as a coding preference, you may want to get in the habit of always including brackets after an if clause. It will keep you from throwing things at the code when you make edits.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer` class. It's a wrapper around `int`, giving you access to such things as `equals()` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: I don't see any need here to wrap the `int`s, just useless overhead.

Comment: Okay i did but like I said to Pescis, it's saying can't find the getFullName() method even though it was in the student class.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the best option (it does the job, though). I guess i focused more on the `int cannot be dereferenced` error than on the actual problem.